# Different use cases and the technical difference and between MyBatis and jOOQ

Tags: java, spring, database, mybatis, jooq

From what I can tell, MyBatis and jOOQ are used for similar cases. So I was wondering when one should use jOOQ over MyBatis in a Spring application and what the technical pros and cons each library and framework brings when developing.

If someone is already proficient in writing SQL queries using a framework like MyBatis, what technical benefits (query runtime, compilation-time error) would switching over to jOOQ bring to them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Product visions

MyBatis's product vision, as I understand it, is to provide a way to implement templating on top of the SQL language, using their XML syntax. The goal is to keep SQL outside of your Java logic in external files (which can be replaced at runtime, e.g. to add hints to your queries), and to use native SQL. ([jOOQ can do that as well](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/03/05/using-java-13-text-blocks-for-plain-sql-with-jooq/), but it's not the most advertised feature). The advantage of using plain SQL is obviously the ability to run your SQL directly in a database client, just like with views or stored procedures as well.

jOOQ's product vision is to offer type safe, embedded, dynamic SQL by implementing SQL as a Java API, and with code generation, offering type safe access to your database schema. The point here is to make your SQL logic *part* of your Java logic, as this will lead to better type safety, and thus quality. Side effects of this are [vendor agnosticity](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/03/13/top-10-sql-dialect-emulations-implemented-in-jooq/) (your SQL will run on many dialects), and very easy [dynamic SQL](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/01/16/a-functional-programming-approach-to-dynamic-sql-with-jooq/). If you have any of these requirements, the choice is easy.

#### Other features of products

The above are the main visions of the respective products, which influence the perception people have of them, but this doesn't keep either products from having additional features which may help you with your every day tasks. I don't know MyBatis well enough - it does seem to have improved a bit on their internal DSL for [dynamic SQL](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-dynamic-sql/) recently, just like jOOQ can be used for occasional templating. A set of [sub-products in MyBatis can be seen here](https://blog.mybatis.org/p/products.html).

Some lesser known jOOQ features that may or may not be of immediate use to your every day work include:

- A rich set of [SPIs and settings](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/) that help control the details of how your generated SQL is produced, including things like identifier qualification ([useful for multi tenancy](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-render-mapping/)), [quoting](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-name-style/), and much more
- [DDL statement support](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/ddl-statements/)
- [Procedural language support](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latestmanual/sql-building/procedural-statements/), to allow for running imperative logic on the server, dynamically
- [Support for a lot of functions](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/)
- [XML and JSON support](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/05/05/using-sql-server-for-xml-and-for-json-syntax-on-other-rdbms-with-jooq/), which can be *very* useful when exporting hierarchical data from the database
- Data [export](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/exporting/) and [import](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/importing/) APIs
- A [SQL parser](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/) ([see also the translator](https://www.jooq.org/translate/))
- A [schema comparison utility](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/schema-diff/) ([see also here](https://www.jooq.org/diff/))
- A [SQL interpreter](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-interpreter/) that can be used to reverse engineer SQL scripts and introspect their meta information programmatically

(Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ)